# CloudFoundry with SteeltoeOSS p-mysql error

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, cloud-foundry

I am trying to setup a microservice structure using Steeltoe with Pivotal Cloud Foundry by following the steps described here: https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/master/MusicStore.
I managed to configure the services, but p-mysql service is using some random username and password:[image] How could I override this?

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to override it.  By default the MySQL service broker will give you new credentials every time you bind / unbind the service instance with an app.  This is intentional as you want to be able to easily rotate your service instance credentials.

If you use the instructions [here](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/master/MusicStore#setup-services-on-cloudfoundry) to setup the services, then you should not really need to do anything else to them.  Notice how the create script [assigns names to the DB instances](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/blob/master/MusicStore/createCloudFoundryServices.sh#L19-L22) that it's creating.

When you run the scripts to push the music store apps, they utilize a manifest.yml file which indicates the service names to bind and use for the app.  Here's an example of the [manifest.yml](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/blob/master/MusicStore/src/MusicStoreService/manifest.yml#L8-L10) file for the music store service app where you can see the manifest file instructing CF which services to bind.

The act of binding is all you need to do to ensure that the app gets the credentials from the service (i.e. what you see listed in Apps Manager).

Also make sure you are following the instructions for deploying to CF, as you can also deploy locally.  [Prerequisites](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/master/MusicStore#pre-requisites---cloudfoundry) for CF, [Service Setup](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/master/MusicStore#setup-services-on-cloudfoundry) for CF, [Building & Pushing](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/master/MusicStore#building--pushing-app---cloudfoundry) for CF.

Comment: The p-mysql service was created using this [dockerrun-mysqlserver.cmd](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/blob/master/MusicStore/dockerrun-mysqlaserver.cmd), so I am not sure how it should work considering that the db service is expecting other credetials. How do I ensure that the app gets the credentials from the service?(the inputs that you see are not editable).

Comment: You don't want to create services with that script.  That's for running the demo's locally.  If you want to run them on CF, you need to use the scripts I mentioned above.

Comment: Right forget that. I created the services using createCloudFoundryServices.cmd. I ran 'pushShoppingCartService.cmd ubuntu.14.04-x64 netcoreapp1.1'. I still get the following error: *'ERR Unhandled Exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Authentication to host 'mysql-broker.local.pcfdev.io' for user 'DvaJab2VglprBI5G' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'DvaJab2VglprBI5G'@'%' to database 'mysql' ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Access denied for user 'DvaJab2VglprBI5G'@'%' to database 'mysql''*

Comment: Hmm, something is trying to access the `mysql` database, which it shouldn't do because that user doesn't have permissions.  Which app is giving you seeing this error?  Have you checked `cf logs --recent` for that app to see if there's more details?  Is the `DvaJab..` the correct user?  i.e. is it picking that up from VCAP_SERVICES correctly?

Comment: I have the error from the logs. The user is the same with the one from [VCAP_SERVICES](https://s4.postimg.org/evoequs4t/vcap.png) config. I am not sure about the password .. Can I somehow try to login to that service without using the application?

Comment: It's a MySQL DB, so you can connect with any valid MySQL client.  An easy option is to push https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/cf-ex-phpmyadmin and bind your service to it.

Comment: The issue was that the user didn't have rights to do CRUD operations on DB. I updated those from mysql workbranch. I am not sure how I can do that using cf.